# Integrating with np.trapz over list of timestamps in Python

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to integrate using the values over the list of timestamp data below, to calculate the mean value which is given by `area/duration` with `np.trapz`

`value_list`:

```
[20.0, 21.0, 23.0, 23.0]
```

`timestamp_list`:

```
[Timestamp('2000-11-08 21:59:41.210000'), Timestamp('2000-11-08 21:59:49.210000'), Timestamp('2000-11-08 21:59:51.210000'), Timestamp('2000-11-08 21:59:53.210000')]
```

Function for area:

```
area =  np.trapz(value_list,dx = np.diff(timestamp_list))
```

I notice `np.trapz` does not work with timestamp data, how can I convert these timestamps in the list to values that suit the purpose of `np.trapz`?

Comment: What's `Timestamp`?

Comment: @QuangHoang it's `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Comment: `area =  np.trapz(value_list, x = timestamp_list)` seems to work fine, no?

Comment: @QuangHoang it returned a value but it doesn't look quite right so I want to confirm with another approach

Comment: The values looks pretty good to me. Why don't you think that it's not correct?

Comment: @QuangHoang please let me have a look, thank you!

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang could you please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65987053/11901732)?